# Entity Manager save changes in Database

Tags: java, sql, database

i have a Question, how to save or update changes in Java end import it to SQL. My Code look like this, but they dont save in DB only in Catche:

```
private EntityManager em;
.
.
.
public boolean reduzieren (int id, int weniger){
Produkt produkt = em.find(Produkt.class,id);
int reduziert = produkt.getPreis - weniger;
produkt.setPreis(reduziert);
return true;
```

should i write em.merge(produkt); to save it in DB. I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate saves Entites to database, when transaction ends. So you should wrap your code in transaction block and it should start working.

Try this.

```java
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();

Produkt produkt = em.find(Produkt.class,id);
int reduziert = produkt.getPreis - weniger;
produkt.setPreis(reduziert);

transaction.commit();
```

Comment: The Code is working, but I dont know how to add  this change to Database.

Comment: As I have said, you should wrap your code with a transaction block. And Hibernate will save changes to database.